# Fancytree enable/disable checkbox based on condition

Tags: fancytree

On fancytrees, I need a solution to enable or disable the checkbox based on a condition.

On the inspector my checkboxes elements are like this:

```
< span role="checkbox" class="fancytree-checkbox"/>
```

Can you please point me some directions?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use this.

```
if(...){
$("#tree").fancytree("option", "checkbox", true});
}
else{
$("#tree").fancytree("option", "checkbox", false});
}
```